# WampServer - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I have been searching around for a while on how to fix this problem but just can't get anywhere.

So I've installed `WampServer` and reinstalled it several times now, when I try to load `localhost/phpmyadmin` I get this error:

`#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

This is also my `config.inc.php` file:

```
/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

No idea what to do really, if I try to load the mySQL console I need to use a password there too which I don't know how to fix. Even when I reinstall the program I get the same errors.

Answer (score -1):

Wamp is usually without a MySQL-password. 
Try replacinng C:/wampdirectory/apps/phpmyadmin-versionthing/config.inc.php, with this version:
(simply remove **THE WHOLE CONTENT** of your current file)

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d';
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

?>